# How to put vim syntax definitions in a ftdetect script?

Tags: vim

Since my filetype is very simple, I would prefer not to create a separate `.vim/syntax` file and just put the definitions in my `.vim/ftdetect` script. That way I can install my filetype with a single symlink to my source dir.

I can do this using `autocmd BufRead *.log`:

```
autocmd BufRead *.log syn match Heading "^## .*$"
autocmd BufRead *.log syn match Comment "^//.*$"
...
```

However this doesn't work when I read from stdin  because of the `*.log` condition. Ideally I should be able to do `:set filetype=vimjournal` to get the syntax highlighting, however the following does not work:

```
autocmd FileType vimjournal syn match Heading "^## .*$"
autocmd FileType vimjournal syn match Comment "^//.*$"
...
```

Note, all the other `autocmd FileType` settings *do* work for this script.

Is it possible to put filetype syntax descriptions in a `ftdetect` script? I don't see much difference from the `*.log` case.

Full script on github: https://github.com/rogerkeays/vimjournal/blob/main/vimjournal.vim

Comment: Your file type being really simple is not really a good reason not to store the syntax definition in the proper location. Just do yourself a favor and store them in the expected location. This should also help other hackers and maintainers that might want to fix or extend your module, they’ll know where to find the existing definitions.

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally I should be able to do :filetype vimjournal

`:h :filetype` is not used this way. What you want is `:setf[iletype] vimjournal` or `:set ft=vimjournal` (the difference between the two is really negligible in your case).

> put the definitions in my .vim/ftdetect script

The whole purpose of `:h ftdetect` is to set `:h 'filetype'` automatically (based on file name and/or contents). As you want the manual setting you don't need it.

Instead, put your syntax commands under `~/.vim/syntax` or `~/.vim/after/syntax` where they ought to be. The file should look like this

```
" standard "guard", just in case
if exists('b:current_syntax')
    finish
endif

" some syntax stuff
syn match ...
syn match ...

" set arbitrary syntax name
let b:current_syntax = '...'
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant `:set filetype=vimjournal` as you suggest. I am just trying to avoid the extra syntax file that you describe. Note: the syntax definitions I want work fine if I use `autocmd BufRead *.log` instead of `autocmd FileType vimjournal` in my ftdetect script.

Comment: full source code here: https://github.com/rogerkeays/vimjournal/blob/main/vimjournal.vim